# AppleScript to get Photos.app Element

Tags: macos, mac, photos, applescript

I've used this AppleScript snippet to get all elements in the Photos UI:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Process Name"
        set visible to true
        return every UI element of front window
        return name of every UI element of front window
    end tell
end tell
```

Despite that, I'm not seeing the element I'm really looking for, which is this one:
[35,884 Photos, 1,556 Videos, Updated Just Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A71nw.png)

Any ideas on how to read from this element? It's been extremely difficult to find any sort of documentation related to scripting Photos. I'd like to output this data to a text file that I'll read for a personal dashboard web app.

EDIT: Here's that element in context: [Element in Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTjo6.png). Apologies for not being able to embed the image. I don't have enough karma to do so.

Comment: Instead of an externally linked picture of just the "35,884 Photos, 1,556 Videos, Updated Just Now", attach an image of that element and where it shows on the iPhoto window, to the question, by editing the question.

Comment: @user3439894 SO won't let me — I don't have enough karma to embed images.

Comment: Are you going to provide the image as requested, even if you have to link it separately, as you did the first one?

Comment: @user3439894 Done.